# What could go wrong with installing the DLCs for fallout new vegas on xbox 360 in the middle of the game

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I have the DLCs and I'm so tempted to install them for cool stuff and more weapons to complete my collection..but I've heard so many bugs and corruptions that have happened to other people's consoles due to other stuff..and this is something big I'm installing to the game and I'm really excited but mainly anxious...and in the middle of the game? Not at the very beginning or after the battle of the dam..but in the middle at a random point.

Comment: I don't recall anything going wrong for me.  Really all you can do is try.

Comment: Ok.................................................

Comment: I'll be waiting for more answers...I wanna do it on a special day...probably like on my birthday..but till then I need answers that say it's ok nothing should go wrong

Comment: Pushasha's answer should be sufficient. I've never run into any issues myself, I'm not sure where you would have got it into your head that something would go wrong. Where did you read/hear about all these "corruptions" when installing DLCs?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing should be wrong with installing the DLC in the middle of the game. When DLC is being tested at Bethesda, some of the QA team uses pre-existing saves, while the rest start new games to test. In short, the developers *expect* you to install the DLC in the middle of a game. So the chance that you'll encounter issues installing it partway through a game is (theoretically) just as high as if you started a new game.

To clarify, if the game worked fine before installing the DLC (excluding known bugs), it should work fine after installing the DLC mid-game. If you encounter bugs after installing the DLC, it likely has nothing to do with the fact that it was installed mid-game -- they would be there no matter what.

Source: [Former QA tester for *Fallout: New Vegas* and *Old World Blues*.](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Sarah_Plotkin)

Comment: Actually, nothing can go wrong, because the DLCs add content.  It's only when you **remove** DLCs that it can cause problems.

Comment: Ok....  ............... .....

Comment: @Nelson I have to respectfully disagree. From my experience as a tester and a modder for this game and other games using this engine, the DLC usually affects the original game content in some small ways. The addition of new items, weapons, buildings, quests, etc. sometimes requires the developers to change the original game in some way, usually to prevent the use of the new content from breaking the old (or vice-versa). When we tested the DLC, many of us were split off and asked to test the main game with the DLC installed, to make sure nothing broke.

Comment: @lordzack01 FYI, if my answer sounds non-committal, it's because I don't want to say, "Yes, I am 100% sure nothing will go wrong". Bethesda's engine is a fickle mistress, and an absurdly large number of variable combinations makes it impossible to say that nothing will go wrong. If it helps, I am 99% sure that nothing will go wrong.

Comment: Ok it's just from research this fallout game was the most unstable and glitchest fallout game made by Bethesda...I've encountered so many new bugs just by transferring the data via data transfer cable ...but it's not prior to the transfer I think it's the new console and the new bugs are varified by fallout wiki aka Bethesda

Comment: @lordzack01 Which is why I didn't guarantee that nothing would go wrong. Not sure what you're talking about with the data transfer cable, but I can assure you that if the game was working fine (excluding the known quest bugs) before you installed the DLC, it should work fine afterward. Any bugs that you encounter are unlikely to be from the fact that you installed it mid-game -- they would be there no matter what.

Comment: Important addition: 100% sure nothing will happen to your old saves as long as you don't save over them. Even if something *did* go wrong after you play a bit, you could still remove the DLC and load the original save to continue without the DLC.